# Passing value to Function through variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have the following dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

vec1 = 1:10 vec2 = 11:20

df = data.frame(col1 = vec1, col2 = vec2)

x <- df %>% summarize(mu = mean(col1, na.rm=TRUE)) x
```

New instead of directly using the col1 in mean function, I want to first save the col1 into a variable and then pass that value to mean. Here is what I want to do.

```
library(dplyr)

vec1 = 1:10 vec2 = 11:20

df = data.frame(col1 = vec1, col2 = vec2)

var = df$col1

x <- df %>% summarize(mu = mean(var, na.rm=TRUE)) x
```

But R doesn't accepts it and and throws the following error.
**Error: unexpected symbol in "x <- df %>% summarize(mu = mean(var, na.rm=TRUE)) x"**

So how do I pass value through a variable into mean?

Comment: don't forget the line break or ; before x

Comment: The error as stated by @Waldi is oonly because of the `x` at the end of the expression.  it should be a different line

Answer (score 0):

Your code works without any error but I think what you were trying to do was :

```
library(dplyr)

var = 'col1'
x <- df %>% summarize(mu = mean(.data[[var]], na.rm=TRUE))
x
```

Comment: Could you explain what    .data[ ] is for?

Comment: `.data` is used to subset columns store as variables (`var1`). This is dynamic and if you want to perform the same calculation for `col2` you only change `var = 'col2'` without changing the code.